# Kubernetes StorageClass for AWS st1/sc1

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to create a StorageClass for AWS EBS to utilise st1 and/or sc1. The StorageClass itself creates fine but utilising it isnt possible due to a minimum size limit

From kube-controller-manager.log:
I0208 15:54:26.132063       5 aws_util.go:137] Error creating EBS Disk volume: InvalidParameterValue: The volume size is invalid for st1 volumes: 1 GiB. st1 volumes must be at least 500 GiB in size. Please specify a volume size above the minimum limit.

How do I specify the volume size within the StorageClass? It seems to default to 1G (the amount being requested in the VolumeClaimTemplate is only 100m per pod); is there a way to override the 1G to be the required 500G? I can't seem to see mention of it anywhere

Thanks!